# I'm facing an Type Error while migrating a component to tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**I have the following component that I'm migrating to TSX.**

```js
import { Component } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import Carousel from "./Carousel";
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorBoundary";
import ThemeContext from "./ThemeContext";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import { PetAPIResponse, Animal } from "./APIResponseTypes";

class Details extends Component<{ params: { id?: string }}> {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    showModal: false,
    animal: "" as Animal,
    breed: "",
    city: "",
    state: "",
    description: "",
    name: "",
    images: [] as string[],
  };



  async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await fetch(
      `http://pets-v2.dev-apis.com/pets?id=${this.props.params.id}`
    );
    const json = (await res.json()) as PetAPIResponse;
    this.setState(Object.assign({ loading: false }, json.pets[0]));
  }
  toggleModal = () => this.setState({ showModal: !this.state.showModal });
  adopt = () => (window.location.href = "https://www.petfinder.com/");
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <h2>loading … </h2>;
    }

    const { animal, breed, city, state, description, name, images, showModal } =
      this.state;

    return (
      <div className="details">
        <Carousel images={images} />
        <div>
          <h1>{name}</h1>
          <h2>{`${animal} — ${breed} — ${city}, ${state}`}</h2>
          <ThemeContext.Consumer>
            {([theme]) => (
              <button
                onClick={this.toggleModal}
                style={{ backgroundColor: theme }}
              >
                Adopt {name}
              </button>
            )}
          </ThemeContext.Consumer>
          <p>{description}</p>
          {showModal ? (
            <Modal>
              <div>
                <h1>Would you like to adopt {name}?</h1>
                <div className="buttons">
                  <a href="https://www.petfinder.com/">Yes</a>
                  <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>No</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Modal>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedDetails = () => {
  const params = useParams<{ id: string }>();
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <Details params={params} />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};

export default WrappedDetails;
```

I see ESlint is showing a problem(**Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.**) in the following line:

> const params = useParams<{ id: string }>();

But I'm clueless on how to fix it. I don't want to disable the line or do anything in the .eslintrc.JSON file.

I've tried to typecast it into many types without success.

I know that The useParams hook returns an object of key/value pairs of the dynamic params from the current URL. I just need to figure out the proper type of `const params`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try creating a *type* like :

```
  type TParams = { id: string };
  let { id }  = useParams<TParams>();
```